# XML-RPC C# How can I create the following XML-RPC with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-rpc

I want to create a request to the following [API Link](https://tdocs.wubook.net/wired/prices.html#update_plan_prices)

```
<methodCall>
  <methodName>update_plan_prices</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>9924436598.9239</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <int>1234234</int>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <int>0</int>
      </value>
    </param>
<param>
  <value>
    <string>10/10/2017</string>
  </value>
</param>
<param>
  <value>
    <struct>
      <member>
        <name>2</name>
        <value>
          <array>
            <data>
              <value>
                <double>1.1</double>
              </value>
              <value>
                <int>2</int>
              </value>
              <value>
                <int>3</int>
              </value>
            </data>
          </array>
        </value>
      </member>
    </struct>
  </value>
</param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

I can't create the right XML for this part

```
<param>
  <value>
    <struct>
      <member>
        <name>2</name>
        <value>
          <array>
            <data>
              <value>
                <double>1.1</double>
              </value>
              <value>
                <int>2</int>
              </value>
              <value>
                <int>3</int>
              </value>
            </data>
          </array>
        </value>
      </member>
    </struct>
  </value>
</param>
```

I tried to create an **object Array** with RoomID and the prices in an Array but i was getting the error response "no prices found"
I also tried to create an **object** with with RoomID and the prices in an Array but i was getting the error response "Tried to change more than 1000 nights". I only had 1 entry in my array with the prices though.

So obviously the methods i tried do not create the correct xml-rpc.
Can anyone help me with that?

I'm using this method to send the request

```
FlRPC proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<FlRPC>();

// First Try
 Object[] pricesObj = new Object[1] { new { id = 1000, data = new int[1] { (int)1 } } }; // this returns the error that no prices are sent
// Second Try
 Object prices = new Object { new { id = 100, data = new int[1] { (int)1 } } } }; // this returns the error that the request contains more than 1000 days to change

var responses = proxy.update_plan_prices("RandToken", 123456, 5454, "01/02/2023", pricesObj); // this method sends the request and gets the response
```

I replaced everything with constant values so there won't be any confusion as to what each value represents

---

I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT
So the pricesObj should be

```
XmlRpcStruct pricesObj = new XmlRpcStruct();
pricesObj.Add("559769", new object[] { 201 });
```

and the definition of the method should change to

```
Object[] update_plan_prices(string token, string lcode, int pid, string dfrom, XmlRpcStruct prices);
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share code that shows what you have tried so far that did not work, i.e. a [mcve]?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of ChatGPT So the pricesObj should be

XmlRpcStruct pricesObj = new XmlRpcStruct();
pricesObj.Add("559769", new object[] { 201 });
and the definition of the method should change to

Object[] update_plan_prices(string token, string lcode, int pid, string dfrom, XmlRpcStruct prices);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).